# A "random page" user script useful to improve the site

Tags: support, site-enhancement

I am trying to navigate our main site to find question and answers to improve:

- Edit posts which I can fix
- Up and down vote what I can
- Vote to close or reopen
- Flag those lengthy comment threads and other broken windows for mod attention

and so on.

However, there seem to be no easy way of finding a "random" selection of posts to review holistically.

Is there a script I can use?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, why, I am surprised you asked!

You can use the very efficient *Random Post v0.1™* user script!

1. Install the user script available [as a gist here](https://gist.github.com/raw/4364586).
2. Go fetch any [Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) page.
3. Notice the die on the top right

   [image]
4. Click on the die to go to a completely random post!

Comment: You may want to post this on [StackApps](http://stackapps.com) as well :)

Comment: @Manishearth It only works on physics, until I figure out how to extract the maximum postId for each site :-)

Comment: GET request http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/info?site=stackoverflow. Use http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/info#filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true to customize the query.

Comment: Alternatively, whenever the user is on the main page,check all the question ids on the page and update a "max_known_postid" variable in `localStorage`. No need for AJAX then.

Comment: @Manishearth thanks. The first method does not give out the MAX(Id), just the COUNT(Id), which is useless to us ... I could do the second but of course stateless would be better :-)

Comment: Thanks for this, Sklivvz. Now if only things could settle down enough that I can find so time to play with it...

Answer (score 2):

While not a script, you can get much more targeted results through the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com).

There are weekly refreshes, so if you're looking for anything less than a week old, it won't show up in the query.

Basically, you want to use the [`newid()` function in SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx) to order by.  A new [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) is produced for every single row (this expression is not evaluated one time and then cached).

That means that you can get a completely random set of questions every time.

Add the `[Post Link]` and then you get a list of URLs that you can use to navigate to the post.

[I've created the following query to be forked](http://data.stackexchange.com/physics/revision/89715/105782/random-questions-on-a-site):

```
select
    p.Id as [Post Link],
    p.* 
from
    Posts as p with (nolock)
where
    --- Just questions for now
    p.PostTypeId in (1) 

    --- Add new filter criteria here
    --- to suit your needs.

order by 
    --- Randomize each time.
    newid()
```

Note the `--- Add new filter criteria here to suit your needs.` comment.  You should adjust the filter in order to target the posts that you specifically want.  For example, you might check the `ClosedDate` column is null to filter out closed posts.

Also note that you can change this query to work on *any* site by selecting "Switch sites" on by the "Run Query" button:

[image: Switch sites option on Stack Exchange Data Explorer]