# Community, help us moderate the site!

Tags: discussion, faq, flagging, moderation

> Related:
>
> [A guide to moderating Physics Stack Exchange yourself: close voting](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1048/a-guide-to-moderating-physics-stack-exchange-yourself-close-voting)
>
> [Community, help us close questions!](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1046/community-help-us-close-questions)

When I first discovered community moderation on this site, I was pretty excited, but I noticed that very few users ever participated in it. Now, as a moderator, I'm on the other side of the fence. From here, I can see that this is still a big issue for our site, and should be fixed.

This post is meant to encourage users to participate in community moderation, as well as introduce them to the basics.

**Do not be intimidated by the length of this post**, you may know about most of the stuff here already. Read the first section (and then maybe the section on flagging), and skim through the rest, looking for what you don't know.

---

[Return to FAQ index](/q/11305)

Answer (score 14):

## What is community moderation, and why should I care?

Community moderation is the "cleaning up" of the site by users like you! It involves flagging, closing, commenting, editing, and sometimes deleting posts. It also involves "implicit" moderation — not doing anything considered inappropriate for this site (e.g. getting involved in long comment discussions which would be better off on chat).

Why should you care? Well, in the end, this is *your* site. You are the community, and by and large you get to decide the path it will take. Helping out by participating in community moderation keeps this site on topic and clean, all in all a fun place to learn from. Neglect community moderation, and it slowly goes on to becoming more and more like most places on the Internet — an untamed wilderness that's no fun to be at.

Yes, as moderators, it *is* our job to keep the site clean. But we cannot do it without participation from the community. We have too many posts coming in to be able to read through all of them, and we can't be in all places at once to keep an eye on things. This is where you come in — you keep a lookout for stuff that needs cleaning, etc., and do your best to address it. This may involve commenting, flagging, and/or closing.

OK, so how do I start?

## The basics of the community moderation tools

### Commenting

*More information on when it is appropriate to use comments can be found in our "[Comment Everywhere](https://physics.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment)" privilege page.*

Comments are pretty simple to use, not much to see here. Later on in this post, I've explained what *not* to use comments for, and also cases in which commenting on a post is good. I'd just like to leave this note here:

When commenting on posts, *be nice*. If it's a new user that you are commenting to, be *welcoming and helpful*. Many times, without knowing it, our comments scare off new users, simply because the comments are *basically* saying "You broke a rule!" — which may sound authoritarian. If you instead try helping them by explaining what went wrong and how to fix it (if it can't be fixed, explain how to avoid it) in a helpful manner, you will not only help keep the site clean, you will also help new users get on their feet. A win-win situation for everyone!

### Flagging

*There's some extra information on this [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/privileges/flag-posts)*.

First, let me explain what flagging is. *Any* user with at least 15 rep, can flag a post. How do you flag? Simple: you click the "flag" link at the bottom of the page. You ought to get a menu like this:

[image: answer flag, no votes]

The exact options shown may vary; the above menu is what you get when you try to flag an answer with no votes.

Anyway, there are quite a few options, and I'll explain when to use them in the sections following this.

A flag basically brings a post to the notice of other users. Custom flags ("it needs ♦ moderator attention") and comment flags are visible only to moderators, and are treated with the strictest confidence. Other flags add an entry for the post in a review queue, where they are processed by users who've crossed certain reputation thresholds.

How do you know if a flag has been acted on? Simple. The flag counts on your profile will update. If you have flagged some posts, you should see something like this on your profile's activity tab:

[image: flag count on main site]

If a flag has been "disputed", declined, or not handled yet, it is not counted here. A flag is marked helpful when either:

- (For non-custom flags) The post is closed/deleted, depending upon the type of flag
- A moderator marks it as helpful

A flag is declined whenever a moderator feels that it is invalid. Do not be discouraged if your flags are declined; instead use the opportunity to learn when to flag and when not to flag. You can see some stats on your flags and with a list of your flags if you click on the number shown on your profile. You ought to see something like:

[image: list of flagged posts]

Declined flags have a reddish "declined" message next to them, as seen above. Be sure to check on these, and learn from them.

Declined flags aren't necessarily a bad thing — if you get too many (as compared to your helpful flags), the number of posts you can flag per day decreases, and your flags have a lower priority. If you get an insane amount of declined flags, the system starts ignoring that, but this is only in extreme cases.

Do *not* be afraid of your flag getting declined. **Flag often, and learn when *not* to flag from your declined flags**.

Also, see if you can improve the post yourself, or leave a comment. Don't leave all the work to the moderators ;-)

[There](https://physics.stackexchange.com/badges/8/citizen-patrol) [are](https://physics.stackexchange.com/badges/67/deputy) [shiny](https://physics.stackexchange.com/badges/82/marshal) badges for flagging.

### Closing/Reopening

*You may also want to see [this page](https://physics.stackexchange.com/privileges/close-questions)*.

As linked in the question, there is a good tutorial on question closing [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1048/a-guide-to-moderating-physics-stack-exchange-yourself-close-voting). So I'll just write a bit about closing in general here.

Unlike on most forums, on Stack Exchange closing is meant to be a *temporary* state. It is a "time out box" for questions which cannot/should not be answered in their current form. Questions that are not salvageable get closed as well, though there is the option of deleting them after a while if they add nothing to the site. Closing a question prevents community members from wasting time in answering something that's not really useful to others — one of Stack Exchange's goals is to Make The Internet Better™ with relevant, informative posts that will be useful to many others.

**Be sure to leave a comment when you vote to close a question**. If the question is salvageable, explain how the user can improve it. If the question isn't, then help the user learn to ask better questions. ([How to Ask](https://physics.stackexchange.com/question/how-to-ask) and the [FAQ](https://physics.stackexchange.com/faq) are useful to link to in such cases).

If you're not sure about closing a post, flag it. For that matter,  it's perfectly OK to flag *and* vote to close a question, at least for now. That way, moderators can help finish it off, though we can find these questions via the close vote review queue as well. Currently, we have a dearth of community moderation and flags, so we can handle extra close-flags. If we are successful in encouraging community moderation, *then* it's better if you don't flag-to-close along with a vote-to-close.

Also: **if you can improve the post yourself, don't hesitate to do so!**

After improving, if you feel that it is now up to the mark for the site, you may **vote to reopen** (or ask for reopening in a custom flag). As mentioned before, closing is a temporary state in most cases.

## What's considered as "bad" here, and how should I deal with it?

There are a lot of things that need to be dealt with. First, lets look at the close reasons. If you find posts that satisfy these criteria, vote to close/flag them as such.

Again, be sure to leave a comment when you vote/flag to post a q. You may want to add a "Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange!" for new users as well. If you cast the last close vote on a salvageable post, then leave a comment "If you do so-and-so, then you may flag this post for mod attention to ask for it to be reopened" or something like that. In many forums, what is known as "closing "is The End for a post, and many users feel it is the same here (and end up complaining instead of simply fixing the post)

#### Exact duplicate

> This question covers exactly the same content as earlier questions on this topic; its answers may be merged with another identical question

This one is pretty self explanatory. If two questions are essentially asking the same thing, and the answers apply in both cases, one can be closed as a duplicate of the other. You need not close according to which was posted second. If one of them has better answers, and/or is better phrased, close the other one as a dupe of it. If they both have good answers and are pretty much *exactly* the same question, flag the post with a custom message asking for a merge.

#### Off topic

> Questions on Physics - Stack Exchange are expected to relate to physics within the scope defined in the FAQ. Consider editing the question or leaving comments for improvement if you believe the question can be reworded to fit within the scope. Read more about closed questions here.

If the question seems to go against:

- the [FAQ](https://physics.stackexchange.com/faq) (specifically the [first](https://physics.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) and [third](https://physics.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask)) sections
- policy discussions on meta
- or your general idea of being on-topic

, then flag/vote to close as off topic. Comment on the reason it is off topic, and maybe tell them to read the FAQ and/or [how-to-ask](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask). Note that a quick way to add a link to the FAQ in comment is by typing `[faq]` in the comment box.

#### Not Constructive

> As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. If you feel that this question can be improved and possibly reopened, see the FAQ for guidance.

This is generally for questions that will end up having many equally valid answers, or those provoking too much discussion. A question should, in the end, have a few answers that are pretty much saying the same thing. Two or three opposing/radically different answers are OK as well, but not more. Examples of NC posts:

- "Make a list"-type questions - these end up with a *lot* of equally valid answers and become a poll. Note that we *do* allow book recommendation questions at the moment, as long as they specify the subtopic and level of understanding required.
- "What do you think about...?" - these promote too much discussion
- "What is the best...?" - not all of these are NC, but some can be. See [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/)

Sometimes, if an NC question (of the "make a list" type) is made rather specific about the criteria, it becomes on topic. If you feel that it is this way, then leave a comment asking for the user to make the criteria more specific. You may still vote-to-close, though — remember, closing is a *temporary* state for such posts.

Again, it's a good idea to leave a comment explaining *why* the post was closed, with some links. You may want to redirect the user to chat (`[chat]` in comments is another magic link), which is the best place for such discussion.

#### Not A Real Question

> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. For help clarifying this question so that it can be reopened, see the FAQ.

This one is mainly about questions that, as mentioned, cannot be reasonably answered in their current form. If (channeling the FAQ, [second section](https://physics.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask)), an *entire book* can be imagined that answers the  question, then  it ought to be closed as NARQ. Another case is when the OP has stuffed >3 questions in the post.

NARQ also works for questions which are too vague/unclear/incomplete, as mentioned in the close message.

NARQ can almost *always* be reopened after some edits. See if you can make the edits yourself (generally it's nearly impossible — it involves some mind-reading). Vote/flag to close, and comment, telling the user that "The question is (too broad/vague/incomplete) at the moment, please (narrow it down/clarify it/complete it)." Or something like that. In the case of 20-million-questions-in-one, tell the OP to prune the list of questions down to a couple of main questions, and/or group the questions into related subgroups and ask as separate posts.

#### Too Localized

> This question is unlikely to help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet. For help making this question more broadly applicable, see the FAQ.

This is the most confusing of them all (in my experience, people understand this one the least), but it's actually rather easy to determine if a post is Too Localized once you get the basic spirit behind it.

The aim of StackExchange is to Make The Internet Better™. This involves having great, informative posts, which will be found useful by many others in the future. If the possible answers to a question will be useful pretty much only to the OP, be useful to others for a short period of time, then the post is Too Localized. This includes many homework questions — if they don't follow the [homework policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/715/7433), then they ought to be closed. I generally comment:

> Welcome to Physics! Please see [our homework policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/715/7433). We expect homework problems to have some effort put into them, and deal with conceptual issues. If you edit your question to explain (1) What you have tried, (2) the concept you have trouble with, and (3) your level of understanding, I'll be happy to reopen this. (Flag this message for ♦ attention with a custom message, or reply to me in the comments with `@Manishearth` to notify me)

on homework questions. Feel free to use that comment, minus the moderator parts, of course :)

Many times, such questions have good conceptual cores. In such cases, they are still not as useful to others, simply because they are hard to find (via Google/etc) — the question title/etc give no hint of the core concept. In such a case, see if you can bring out the conceptual part of the question by editing it. Or comment on it asking the OP to do so.

### Other problem posts

Now on to the other types of "problem" posts

#### Things that don't answer the question

> This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

If someone posts an answer that seems to be meant as a comment or edit, flag it as "not an answer" (leave a comment explaining how to comment/edit as well. Note that users with <50 rep cannot comment).

Also, if the post is answering an *entirely different* question (happens at times), this can also be flagged as NAA. Note that NAA is *not* for wrong answers. If you feel an answer is wrong, down vote and comment. Don't flag unless it has other issues.

#### Very Low Quality posts

> This question/answer has severe formatting or content problems. This question is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

If the post is extremely short/is just gibberish/or is otherwise of very bad quality, then flag it as VLQ. Note that we generally don't delete short answers, though it's something that's better dealt with on a case-by-case basis, so flag away!

Link-only answers should be commented on and down voted. Nothing wring with flagging them, but we generally don't act on those.

#### Plagiarism

[This post pretty much covers how you deal with plagiarism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160071/what-to-do-when-plagiarism-is-discovered). A custom mod flag doesn't hurt here if you want us to look into it.

#### Spam/Promotion

If a post is a blatant promotion of a site (and isn't really useful), flag it as spam. If the post is a valid answer but links to a blog post which seems to belong to the posting user, then comment, asking the user to reveal their affiliation, if any. You may want to link to [this section of the FAQ](https://physics.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion). If too many of their posts are used to promote their blog, custom flag their posts.

#### Offensive

> This answer contains content that a reasonable person would consider offensive, abusive, or hate speech.

Flag the post as "not welcome in our community" if you feel that it satisfies the criteria above

### Comments

Now, about comments.

First of all, comments are third-class citizens on this site. Their purpose is to aid the user in improving a post. If improvements from a comment have been made, or if the comment will not lead to more improvements, then they may be deleted. Long discussions ought to be sent to chat. The comment flag button is visible on the left of the comment when you hover over it.

#### Chatty comments

If a comment is "chatty", i.e., provoking irrelevant discussion and/or a "thank you" comment, flag it as such. Stuff that praises the post/etc can be removed after the OP has had a chance to see it. Most of the comments [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/14968/7433) can be considered "chatty"

#### Obsolete

If the result of a comment/comment thread has been edited into the post, you may flag the comment(s) as obsolete. You may alternatively custom flag a comment (or the post itself) requesting cleanup of obsolete comments when there are many of them.

#### Rude/offensive

Self explanatory

#### Not Constructive/Off topic

If you feel that the comment is off topic here (i.e., it's not related to the post/comments), then flag it as such. This option is also for comments which you feel would be better off deleted — they may provoke unnecessary drama/discussion.

#### Other

Of course, if there's something else wrong with a comment, you may always use this option.

## Finding posts that need attention and Review queues

While you can find many such posts just by exploring the site (or by using the tools [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2889/a-random-page-user-script-useful-to-improve-the-site)), and you *should* do this, there is a "fast track" of finding such posts, the [review queues](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review).

What are these? Well, they are filled with posts that possibly need community attention, as determined by the system or other community users. You are shown these posts, one at a time, and you "review" them. Like flagging, [there](https://physics.stackexchange.com/badges/106/custodian) [are](https://physics.stackexchange.com/badges/85/reviewer) [badges](https://physics.stackexchange.com/badges/107/steward) for this.

So, what consists a "review"? It depends on the queue. The queues have one consistent option, though — the "skip" option. This permanently skips the post (you won't see it in the same review queue again), and is useful if you're not sure what to do.

Each user has their own copy of the queue — if you review a post in a queue, it is not necessarily removed from that queue for other users. It gets removed for all users after a few more reviews by other users (the exact amount depends upon the queue and review action done). For example, all my review queues are empty, because I have reviewed/skipped everything that was in them. This doesn't mean that the posts are removed from your queues as well.

### The Late Answers and First posts queue

These are available to you once you get 125 rep on the site. The Late answers queue contains answers which were posted much later than the question (and thus don't get as much attention, the purpose of this queue is to give them attention). The First posts contains the first few posts asked by new users (who will probably need help learning to use the site).

Here, all you have to do is edit the post, flag it, up vote it, add a comment, or up vote a previously existing comment, and the "I'm done" option is unlocked. If you feel that the post is fine as it is, but you don't want to vote on it (you're not *that* impressed with it, etc), then you can always choose the "no action needed" button.

Be sure to do as much as possible to improve the post — fix grammar/links/images/LaTeX, comment asking for more details, etc.

After a few users have reviewed a post (IIRC, it is 3). it is removed from the queue for all.

### Low Quality queue

Here, low quality posts are listed. If you feel that a post is OK for the site and cannot be improved further, click "Looks good". Else, edit/comment, and *then* click "looks good".

If you feel that it ought to be deleted, click the "delete" button. This pops up a menu that lets you choose a boilerplate comment to place. Use this option even if the post isn't really deletable, but is worthy of one of the boilerplate comments listed there.

For users with <10k rep, this doesn't really delete the post. It just prioritizes it in the queue for those who can (so don't be afraid of using it!). Those with 10k+ rep, when clicking this button, automatically cast a delete vote on the post.

### Close/Reopen vote queues

You get access to these at 3k rep, along with the privilege to vote to close/reopen posts.

Questions that may need closing/reopening appear in these queues. Questions with open close votes/close flags show up in the close queue, and questions with open reopen votes, as well as questions which have been edited after closing appear in the reopen queue.

In this queue, you have four options. You can try to fix a close-able post via the "edit" button. You also can vote to close it. (In the case of the reopen queue, obviously the corresponding option is voting to reopen) You can, as usual, skip it. And finally, you can select "leave open". What does this last option do? If two people vote to "leave open"/"leave closed", the post is removed from the close/reopen queue(respectively) for everyone. This does *not* clear close/reopen votes on the post.

Along with the 10k moderator tools (see above), this is one of the best ways to find posts that need closing.

### Suggested edit queue

At 2k reputation, you can approve suggested edits on posts, and at 5k reputation, you can approve edits on tag wikis. Users without enough rep to edit have their edits placed in this queue. If two users approve an edit (if one rejects and one approves then it waits for more users to review it), then it is published. If you feel that the edit is:

- too minor: not much added, the post was fine without the edit
- vandalism: it made the post worse
- radical change: it modified the post so that it may no longer be what the author meant it to be
- invalid: it was probably supposed to be a comment or an answer
- copied: the edit is just a copy-paste from an external source without block-quoting and attribution

then, reject it as such.

You can also "improve" a suggested edit. This is when you notice that the post has other things which can be improved as well, and you get to edit the post. Here, you may also choose whether or not to mark the suggested edit as "helpful" (if not marked as such, the edit is rejected, though your "improve" edit still goes through). Too many rejected suggested edits block a user from suggesting more for a while; keep this in mind while rejecting edits.

There is one more queue, but it's not always visible and it isn't a community moderation thing.

## Meta participation

Lastly, an aspect of community moderation(sort of) is *deciding* site policies. This is done on this site, [Physics Meta](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/). Here, we have discussions about the site policies/etc (as well as help users who need it), and you are welcome to join in! Participating in meta familiarizes you with site policies, and you get to play an active part in formulating them You may want to read the [Meta FAQ](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/faq) first, though, especially [the section on voting](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/faq#vote-differences).

Comment: Ok, I've been reading this for almost 1/2 an hour. I think I've understood something. But one thing - "Isn't the suggested edit privilege for 2k" *now*..?

Comment: Maybe thats why, "Chris and Me" are retagging imported astronomy posts :-)

Comment: And one more thing: (Regarding the flagging appearance) - Nah, I haven't seen the declined flags (red colored) in brackets. It simply appears [something like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/S9pRD.png). I mean, only the *"Blue one"*. Not a big deal though. Just to notify you :-)

Comment: @CrazyBuddy: Really? I see the red number on your profile. And it's not a mod-only superpower to see the red number (well, it _is_ one to see the flag counts on  any profile) -- because the screenshot I took was from MSO, where I have no diamond.

Comment: Err... Sorry for that. Well, I thought we're dealing with Physics.SE.

Comment: @CrazyBuddy: The same system(pretty much_ is behind Phy.SE and MSO. If I can see my declined count on MSO, you should be able to see your helpful count on Phys main/meta (you do have a declined count on both). Dunno why that's not working...

Comment: [**PDF for offline reading**](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/28613587/Physics/community-help-us-moderate-the-site.pdf)

Comment: @Sklivvz: Thanks :)

Comment: [gist](https://gist.github.com/4407869) for off-site editing, forking etc.

Comment: @Sklivvz: Hi Sklivvz. Just came to say "Thats wonderful" - You could post this as some answer or something below the question *itself* so that many would get an attention :-)

Comment: @CrazyBuddy: No need, I edited it in :)

Comment: @CrazyBuddy: Course you didn't, I added it right now! :P

Comment: @Manishearth: Well, I re-edited my comment after seeing your revision history (which you didn't notice) :-)

Comment: @Manishearth I just noted that this answer (and many other similar posts) are almost exclusively focused on how to help closing, deleting, flagging, and generally "cleaning" up bad things. It would be nice to have a not too small paragraph inserted about how to (edit) + flag to **reopen** for people who have not 3000rep, community reopen for people who have more than 3000rep, undelete wrongly deleted things, etc ... These "positive" aspects of community moderation (reopen, undelete, etc) are as important as the "cleaning up" business I think.

Comment: @Dilaton: Firstly, if you read this post carefully, you'd realize that in most cases closing _is_ a positive aspect. Also, what you mention above is actually going to be baked into the system (there are major changes to the close system coming in the next few months). I'll edit it in though (though there's a lot about it in the review queue section and the close section does advocate fixing in many places)

Comment: Also, the point of community moderation _is_ to either fix bad things or make them go away by removing them. And if you notice, this post deals with both.

Comment: @Manishearth thanks for mentioning reopen too now :-). There are two converse approaches to improve the site one can take: The first one is to discourage bad stuff and make it go away by downvoting, closing, deleting, and other punishments. This approach assumes that most people have bad intentions, are lazy, too dumb to to it right, etc. This is why I call this approach "negative", because it presumes that everything is bad and people behave bad and do bad things on purpose, and this has to be counteracted to improve the site. This approache takes the philosophy that the glass is half empty.

Comment: The second approach is to **encourage** good and interesting things by upvotes, try to find the good thing in things people are posting, help them to improve it furter if it is not yet perfect, treat people and their posts in a respectful manner and make them feel valuable and welcome. This second approach assumes that most people who come here have no bad intentions, are smart, their posts are valuable and takes their needs seriously. This second approach looks at things from the positive side, the glass is half full and some people just need some help.

Comment: @Manishearth I personally favor the second approach which looks at things from a more positive point of view for the "everyday business" here, whereas I acknowledge that in exceptional situations, such as spam, insults, attacks, and other very bad things, the first approache is approapriate too. You and the other MSO people seem to almost exclusively focus on the first "negative" approach when wanting to improve things (?), which is unfurtunate and certainly discouraging some people. It is the reason why I almost never post on MSO, whereas on Math SE they apply the second positive approach.

Comment: @Dilaton: Again, these are not two _approaches_ . These are two tools which complement each other. Closing _is not a bad thing_; it't only temporary and is an "on hold" state in most cases. Read my section above on closing thoroughly. Notice that on most closed posts, we comment explaining how to improve it if possible. That's a positive, handholding approach that helps everyone. We never assume bad intentions (except for obvious spam et al).

Comment: Try to understand this: If an unclear post was not closed, it would get speculatory answers that try to guess what the OP is asking. A waste of time all around, when the post could have been simply improved. So all we do is put it in an on hold state where it can be improved but not answered. This applies to most close reasons as well. NC posts can be improved (as you well know). We don't want one-line recommendation answers flooding the site. So it gets closed till the question is asking for something better.

Comment: With this in mind, closing is not _negative_. I agree that it leaves a negative impact on the user due to the wording, but this is being changed soon. (In a few months, a closed question will be called "on hold" and will say something like "this has been put on hold and cannot receive answers until the following issues are addressed", after which it lists the issues and how to fix them). But it is a good thing: It leaves a post on hold until it can be improved, which in turn will improve the quality of the answers it will eventually receive.

Comment: Also, alluding to "MSO people" and "MSO mentality" is really demeaning. Please stop. This is a matter of network policy, not MSO policy.

Comment: @Manishearth yes, many network policies and the corresonding mentalities are way to negative in my personal outsider opinion as I observe it (too focused on downvote, delete, close, punishments, restrictions of what can be done by the communities of and what content is allowed on the individual smaller sites etc). My comments are **NOT** meant to be an insult, offense, or something like that, this is just how I perceive it when silently lurking and reading stuff from time to time on MSO. I thought MSO mostly deals with network wide policies? Anyway, we dont have to continue this discussion ...

Comment: @Dilaton: Ah, the reason behind this is simple: The "positive" things don't need any policies. To make the "negative" things work correctly you need to outline how and when they need to be used. That's why you feel that MSO is negative. From my experience, there are tons of positive posts as well. Yes, MSO is network wide, but this particular policy doesn't come from MSO.

Comment: @Manishearth BTW too often questions get closed because the closing reader is not knowledgable enought to understand the question (he thinks the question is unclear because of this), whereas people familiar with the subject or topic, the ones who could potentially answer too, perfectly understand it. This IS a bad thing, and is among other things why I always say people moderating should have some knowldeg about the stuff they are moderating ... Maybe such bad closures are a drawback of the knowldedge level of people here being too widely scattered...

Comment: @Dilaton: From what I've seen, usually this is not the case. Remember that it takes 5 votes to close, and mods generally don't use the vote unless it's an obvious case (or if we have discussed it internally). Most close reasons deal with stuff that can be figured out without knowing the topic fully. However, if you come across such a case, calmly leave a comment. No need to get worked up about it, ever: All of this is reversible. If it does get closed, ping one of us in chat or whatever, and explain the situation

Comment: @Dilaton: By the way (don't take this in a bad way, it's just an observation): I've noticed that you get very worked up when an action you disagree with happens, and leave long comments/flags when that happens. Usually these comments have a line of explanation and many lines of not-really-relevant stuff. Whenever you see something you disagree with, calmly elucidate the reasons why you think the action should not have been taken. Most things are reversible, no need to get worked up about it.

Comment: Most importantly, don't get lost in political dithering: If you can explain why the post fits Phys.SE's rules (even better: fix it so that it is clearer), then that is awesome. Not saying you do this all the time, just that I've noticed that you have a tendency to do so. Again, please don't take offense, I'm only trying to show you how we can work together in a better way.

Comment: You may want to update the close reasons...

Comment: @DoubleAA will do so when I get the time
, thanks for the reminder.

Comment: I'd appreciate if you could add an answer with the "why is moderation important" part, on my question here: https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/q/3300/4506 !

Answer (score -8):

I would prefer it rather to see the community doing good questions and answers.

Is such an increase or additional amount of moderation by activities like closing, flagging, hunting artifically posts that could be not quite apprropriate etc really needed here ...? I think it would be better to concentrate on good physics, until really bad things happen that need action.

I have noticed that the closing business for example was going a bit too well recently, since some good, appropriate, and interesting questions were victims of this increased closings frequency too. Having to struggle that (wrongly) closed questions get reopend distracts one from doing and enjoying physics.

I thought doing physics is the main topic and purpose of Physics SE.

Comment: I though people were too concerned with flagging and duplicates and rep, but this article suggests they're not concerned enough.
Forget the rep, do the Physics.

Comment: Physics _is_ the main topic and purpose. Which is going along pretty well here at the moment. Community moderation, on the other hand, is not going well; users with privileges are not using them. We would prefer it (and I think you would as well), if question closes were done by the community.

Comment: If the site isn't adequately moderated, we slowly become like a forum. Check out PhysicsForums or something--I personally find the site nearly useless, since a lot of the good content is buried beneath irrelevant discussion, and most of the posts are homework help. You yourself complained about too many HW qs a while ago.

Comment: S/slowly/quickly/

Comment: Hi @Manishearth, yeah I am very concerned about the level of this site and that most of the questions at present ask for homework help. But reading chat and meta, it seems that people are more concerned about increasing the number of closures questions and flags, imposing SE policy, prevent that nobody says the slightest thing that anybody hypersensitive could (mis)understand as rude, etc than about the level and physics content of the site ...

Comment: In view of the increasing homeworkiness, I am much more concerned about the question if we do enough and the right things to keep experts and generally knowledgabe people interested and comfortable in contributing to physics SE. And I am not convinced that an increase of moderation is (the only and unique) solution to attract more experts and knowledgable contributers to physics SE. Generally demanding to largely increase the number of closures of question is a mixed blessing, if to many good and legitimate questions get wrongly closed too, the can turn off people who like and know physics ...

Comment: @Raindrop I too think that people are too concerned with flagging, closing, etc instead of physics ... :-/. This article only suggests that some people like the closing, flagging, etc to increase even further, and I am not sure if this is a good thing which will help improve the physics. What I like is your amazing efforts to get stuff answered by sponsoring many bounties, this is very selfless :-)

Comment: @Dilaton: Uhh, I'm demanding to increase the number of closures, I want more _community_ closures (instead of us mods doing all of it). We have a lot of posts which should be closed, but aren't. To be clear, I'm not trying to make it so that the criteria for "closeable question" is widened. I'm trying to just get the community to participate more. The questions will be eventually closed either way, just that if the community participates, it is less of a unilateral mod decision, and more of something that five community members agree on. This will _reduce_ incorrect closures.

Comment: Furthermore, you have mentioned that "some good, interesting, questions were closed"  and "Having to struggle that (wrongly) closed questions get reopend distracts one from doing and enjoying physics." -- those questions were _correctly_ closed, you know that (refer to your meta post).

Comment: I never said that an increase of moderation is the only way to attract new users to SE, don't put words in my mouth. I said that it is _necessary_ for this site to succeed. Of course, we need other things as well to attract new users.

Comment: @Dilaton, if you want less homework questions, the only way is to close and delete such questions. The moderators can't be expected to have eyes everywhere and keep the site clean by themselves. We as a community must help. *This is why this question is up, and also why it is important to you.*

Comment: If you are worried about the number of users, increasing the influx will never save the community if everyone wants to leave due to non-physics related quarrels, playground-bully-style insults and so on. The large majority of users wants just quality answers, quality questions and a community of decent and welcoming people focused on helping. I think this question represents *exactly* the kind of positive attitude that will make this place great again (while in beta this was a great community). Try to focus on the positive and not always complain about the negative like above.

Comment: Moderation is important and I support moderation, I just dislike it when people spend too much time moderating just one question and having lengthy discussions about 'should I delete this question', IMO moderation should be an efficient and time-saving system.

Comment: @Raindrop: Exactly. It should be a community-voted process, where a few community members voice their opinion on it by casting a close/delete/whatever vote, and that's it. Currently, we mods are closing/deleting quite a few posts unilaterally (we try not to), without consulting anyone (except sometimes each other or the chat room). This leads to more disagreements over the closing/etc. If a question is community-closed, we all know that there are at least five community members who agree, which can prevent  lengthy discussion.

Comment: We're supposed to be exception handlers--only dealing with stuff the community can't, but right now we're dealing with stuff the community _won't_. Not good.

Comment: @Manishearth I now better understand what you mean and agree, I did for example not think about that an increase of communitiy closures (while keeping the total number of them about constant) could in fact decrease the bad closures and therefore the hassle ... BTW your manual is really good ;-)

Comment: @Sklivvz I agree with you here ;-), all I want is good quality questions and answers too and enough knowledgable people around such that one can learn physics together with nice people here. Without being distracted from physics by bad things all the time...

Comment: Writing good quality = More good quality. Moderaating = (hopefully) Less Bad Quality